# How to parallelize an xgboost fit?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to fit many xgboost models with different parameters (e.g. for parameter tuning). Running them in parallel is needed to reduce time. However, upon running the `%dopar%` command I get the following error: `Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection`.

Below is a reproducible example. It has to do with xgboost, since any other calculation involving global variables works within the `%dopar%` loop. Could someone point out what is missing/wrong with this approach?

```
#### Load packages
library(xgboost)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#### Data Sim
n = 1000
X = cbind(runif(n,10,20), runif(n,0,10))
y = 10 + 2*X[,1] + 3*X[,2] + rnorm(n,0,1)

#### Init XGB
train = xgb.DMatrix(data  = X[-((n-10):n),], label = y[-((n-10):n)])
test  = xgb.DMatrix(data  = X[(n-10):n,],    label = y[(n-10):n]) 
watchlist = list(train = train, test = test)

#### Init parallel & run
numCores = detectCores()
cl = parallel::makeCluster(numCores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(xgboost)
})

pred = foreach(i = 1:10, .packages = c("xgboost")) %dopar% {
  xgb.train(data = train, watchlist = watchlist, max_depth=i, nrounds = 1000, early_stopping_rounds = 10)$best_score
 # if xgb.train is replaced with anything else, e.g. 1+y, it works
} 

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Have you seen the `train` function from the `caret` package? This allows for a grid search of tuning parameters and allows a lot of flexibility and parallel processing using the `trainControl` function.

Comment: just a guess but it may be because `xgboost` is already parallelized. You can pass the parameter `nthread` eg. `params=list(nthread= numCores)`

Comment: Objects created by **xgboost**, such as 'xgb.DMatrix' objects, cannot be saved to and read from disk or be passed on to another R process, which means they also cannot be used in parallelization.  This is explained in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html.  Instead, as @Chris says, use the multithreading parallelization that comes with **xgboost** built-in.

Comment: Based on the point made by @HenrikB might a solution be to bring the creation of the `xgb.DMatrix` inside of the `foreach`? Additional overhead but that might allow parellelization

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks a lot @HenrikB and @Chris, putting `train`, `test` and `watchlist` inside of `foreach` does the trick. @Chris, I am aware of the `nthread` argument, however that is for within training of a single model and doesn't add much to the speed, especially when compared to parallelizing the training itself, at least in my case. Please post an answer so I can mark it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments by HenrikB `xgb.DMatrix` objects can't be used in parallelization. To get around this we can make the object inside of `foreach`:

```r
#### Load packages
library(xgboost)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
#> Loading required package: iterators

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')

#### Init parallel & run
numCores = detectCores()
cl = parallel::makeCluster(numCores, setup_strategy = "sequential")
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
  
  
  
  
pred = foreach(i = 1:10, .packages = c("xgboost")) %dopar% {
    # BRING CREATION OF XGB MATRIX INSIDE OF foreach
    dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.train$data, label = agaricus.train$label)
    dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.test$data, label = agaricus.test$label)
    
    watchlist = list(dtrain = dtrain, dtest = dtest)
    
    param <- list(max_depth = i, eta = 0.01, verbose = 0,
                  objective = "binary:logistic", eval_metric = "auc")
    bst <- xgb.train(param, dtrain, nrounds = 100, watchlist, early_stopping_rounds = 10)
    bst$best_score
    } 

stopCluster(cl) 
pred
#> [[1]]
#> dtest-auc 
#>  0.892138 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> dtest-auc 
#>  0.987974 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> dtest-auc 
#>  0.986255 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> dtest-auc 
#>         1 
#>  ...
```

#### Benchmarking:

Since `xgboost.train` is already parellalized, it might be interesting to see the difference in speeds between when threads are used for `xgboost` vs when used for the parallel running of tuning rounds.

To do this I wrapped in a function and benchmarked the different combinations:

```r
tune_par <- function(xgbthread, doparthread) {
  
  data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
  data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
  
  #### Init parallel & run
  cl = parallel::makeCluster(doparthread, setup_strategy = "sequential")
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
  
  clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
    data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
  })
  
  
  
  pred = foreach(i = 1:10, .packages = c("xgboost")) %dopar% {
    dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.train$data, label = agaricus.train$label)
    dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.test$data, label = agaricus.test$label)
    
    watchlist = list(dtrain = dtrain, dtest = dtest)
    
    param <- list(max_depth = i, eta = 0.01, verbose = 0, nthread = xgbthread,
                  objective = "binary:logistic", eval_metric = "auc")
    bst <- xgb.train(param, dtrain, nrounds = 100, watchlist, early_stopping_rounds = 10)
    bst$best_score
  } 
  
  stopCluster(cl) 
  
  pred
  
}
```

In my testing evaluation was faster when using more threads for xgboost and less for the parallel running of tuning rounds. What works best probably depends on system specs and the amount of data.

```r
# 16 logical cores split between xgb threads and threads in dopar cluster:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  xgb16par1 = tune_par(xgbthread = 16, doparthread = 1),
  xgb8par2 = tune_par(xgbthread = 8, doparthread = 2),
  xgb4par4 = tune_par(xgbthread = 4,doparthread = 4),
  xgb2par8 = tune_par(xgbthread = 2, doparthread = 8),
  xgb1par16 = tune_par(xgbthread = 1,doparthread = 16),
  times = 5
)
#> Unit: seconds
#>       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
#>  xgb16par1 2.295529 2.431110 2.500170 2.519277 2.527914 2.727021     5 a   
#>   xgb8par2 2.301189 2.308377 2.407767 2.363422 2.465446 2.600402     5 a   
#>   xgb4par4 2.632711 2.778304 2.875816 2.825471 2.849003 3.293593     5  b  
#>   xgb2par8 4.508485 4.682284 4.752776 4.810461 4.822566 4.940085     5   c 
#>  xgb1par16 8.493378 8.550609 8.679931 8.768008 8.779718 8.807943     5    d
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the benchmarks.  It would be interesting to see what you get if you move the cluster setup and teardown (`makeCluster()`/`stopCluster()`), which comes with a big overhead, outside of the function.  Same for `registerDoParallel()`. Setting up the cluster once per session should ne a more common use.

Comment: BTW, there are only 10 elements to parallelize over in the `foreach()` call, so there will be at most 10 parallel workers used, in contrast to the 16 you have available.  Increasing the number of elements to 16 will probably give a better number.