# How to parallelize a lightgbm fit?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lightgbm

I am trying to fit many `lightgbm` models with different parameters (e.g. for parameter tuning). Running them in parallel is needed to reduce time. However, upon running the `%dopar%` command I get the following error: `Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection`.

The same issue came up with `xgboost` (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66661306/how-to-parallelize-an-xgboost-fit)) and the problem was solved by incorporating the xgboost datatypes `xgb.DMatrix` that train and test data was stored as into the `%dopar%` loop itself instead of outside of it. However, with `lightgbm` this doesn't work either (i.e. putting the native `lgb.Dataset` train and test datasets within the loop still brings the same error). Any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit: I am using Windows10, R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15), RStudio version 1.4.1106 Win64, lightgbm version 3.1.1. The code apparently works for Mac, as mentioned in the comments.

Below is a reproducible example. (I am aware that `lightgbm` incorporates its own parallelization via the `nthread` argument (just like `xgboost`), but that uses parallelization *within* the fit, which doesn't seem to be bringing much speed improvement for me.)

```
#### Load packages
library(lightgbm)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#### Data Sim
n = 1000
X = cbind(runif(n,10,20), runif(n,0,10))
y = 10 + 2*X[,1] + 3*X[,2] + rnorm(n,0,1)

#### LGB - single (works)
train = lgb.Dataset(data  = X[-nrow(X),], label = y[-nrow(X)])
test  = lgb.Dataset(data  = t(as.matrix(X[nrow(X),])), label = y[nrow(X)]) # 1 step-ahead only
valid = list(train = train, test = test)
model_lgb = lgb.train(data  = train, valids = valid, max_depth = 31, eta = 0.1, num_rounds = 10000, obj = "regression", early_stopping_rounds = 25)

#### LGB - parallel (doesn't work)
numCores = detectCores()
cl = parallel::makeCluster(numCores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(lightgbm)
})
    
pred_lgb = foreach(i = 1:8, .packages = c("lightgbm")) %dopar% {
  train = lgb.Dataset(data  = X[-nrow(X),], label = y[-nrow(X)])
  test  = lgb.Dataset(data  = t(as.matrix(X[nrow(X),])), label = y[nrow(X)]) # 1 step-ahead only
  valid = list(train = train, test = test) 
  model_lgb = lgb.train(data  = train, valids = valid, max_depth = i, eta = 0.1, num_rounds = 10000, obj = "regression", early_stopping_rounds = 25)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Result:

```
  Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
```

Comment: Can you please update this question with information about the version of `{lightgbm}` you are using, which operating system you are on, and which version of R you are using? With {lightgbm} 3.1.1 (the latest on CRAN), on my Mac, using R 4.0.3, your code did not produce an error and all 8 training runs succeeded for me.

Comment: @JamesLamb, thanks for pointing out the pipeline operator which I now removed from the code. Interesting that it works on your Mac. I am using Windows10, R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15), RStudio version 1.4.1106 Win64, lightgbm version 3.1.1.  I recently even uninstall & reinstalled everything so everything is up to date. Still getting the error. I would be curious to know if it works for anyone on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally ran the reproducible example again today and it *did* work. In my original code I had additional packages in the `clusterEvalQ` segment, which I think I removed prior to posting the code here (since they are redundant for this reproducible example) without running it again myself - admittedly, that would be a blatant mistake, but can't find any other explanation.

So it seems that there is a problem when loading multiple packages via `clusterEvalQ` in addition to `lightgbm`. Leaving only `lightgbm` in `clusterEvalQ` and loading the necessary additional packages in the `foreach` loop via the `.packages` functions fixes it, like this:

```
#### LGB
numCores = detectCores()
cl = parallel::makeCluster(numCores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(lightgbm) 
  # no additional packages here
})

# additional packages here
pred_lgb = foreach(i = 1:8, .packages = c("additionalPackage", "lightgbm")) %dopar% {
  train = lgb.Dataset(data  = X[-nrow(X),], label = y[-nrow(X)])
  test  = lgb.Dataset(data  = t(as.matrix(X[nrow(X),])), label = y[nrow(X)]) # 1 step-ahead only
  valid = list(train = train, test = test) 
  model_lgb = lgb.train(data  = train, valids = valid, max_depth = i, eta = 0.1, num_rounds = 10000, obj = "regression", early_stopping_rounds = 25)$best_iter
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

I still need to research the difference between the two ways of loading packages. Note that this problem does *not* occur with `xgboost`, i.e. I can load multiple packages without error in `clusterEvalQ`.